# Returning views using controller present somewhere else other than Views folder

Tags: laravel, module

How to return view present somewhere other than views folder from the controller in Laravel? I am making a project divided into modules. I want to return the view of the module from the controller of the main project. How to do it?
Because currently when I try to route to other links it shows:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8895

Routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
Route::post('/navpage1',[
'uses'=>'ProjectController@nextpage1',
'as'=>'navpage1'
]);
Route::post('/navpage2',[
'uses'=>'ProjectController@nextpage2',
'as'=>'navpage2'
]);
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class ProjectController extends BaseController 
{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

 public function nextpage1()
{
    return   view('C:/xampp/htdocs/larve/app\Modules\Course_Entry\views\welcome');
}

public function nextpage2()
{
    return view('C:/xampp/htdocs/larve/app\Modules\Log_in_blog_post\views\welcome');
}
}
```

App/Modules/ServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules;
class ServiceProvider extends  \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{
    $modules = config("module.modules");
    while (list(,$module) = each($modules)) {
        if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/web.php')) {
            include __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/web.php';
        }
        if(is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views')) {
            $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', $module);
        }
    }
}
public function register(){}
}
```

I know something is wrong with my controller, but i am just trying to figure out how to do it...
I have given more code here: [Laravel program divided into modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215697/laravel-program-divided-into-modules)

Comment: Could you post some code? The issue you're having doesn't seem to be related to the location of your view but more to your routing.

Comment: Okay.. I have added my routes and controller file

Comment: And when are you getting the error? What is the request that you do?

Comment: I am getting the error when I try to click on my navigation bar to go to the specific module.(I edited the code again, edited my web.php file of the modules)

Comment: There was an error in my routes file of the modules, I just added my previous routes inside Route::group(array('module'=>'Course_Entry','namespace' => 'Modules\Course_Entry\Controllers'), function() {.
.
.
.
});

Answer (score 0):

change the paths in app->config->view.php.

```
'paths' => [
     realpath(base_path('app\Modules\Log_in_blog_post\views')),
 ],
```

then use in controller:- view('welcome').

Comment: But, I have a view in the main project, and two views in the two modules. I provided the Modules folder with a service provider file: (Just added in the question). This is the firest time I am making a modular laravel project, and  have certain issues:
1. How to view my main file and then it will linkn to the two modules since it contains a nav bar navigating to these two pages.

Comment: 2. I am not having any migrations of my modules here, then how are these migrated to my database, for now I migrated them before making them as a single project.

Comment: Please check my this que: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215697/laravel-program-divided-into-modules

Comment: http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/

Comment: you can't use my above answer

Comment: Yes, I know.But the problem is I don't know what to use either @Twonim Faisal

Comment: I have read it, I have done it, Actually, I am confused about further steps. @Townim Faisal